# Day translation

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I'm trying to translate a day of the week from one language to another.

I have `string` like `Monday` and I want to have the same day to another locale.
Is this possible with `Moment.js`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this -

```
moment("01-06-2018", 'MM-DD-YYYY').locale("fr").format("dddd");
```

In your case, this would be -

```
moment("Monday", 'dddd').locale("fr").format("dddd")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this with `moment` you can do it like this

```
moment().isoWeekday('Monday').locale('nl').format('dddd')
```